# Double Click OnClickListener of a Recycler View Adapter

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I am trying to add a simple Click View to an item of a recycler view, but for some reason I have to click on an item twice instead of once to perform an action. On single click it seems like that recycler View does not detect a click. On the next one however it detects the click and performs a suitable action.

XML :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_inventory_recycler_item"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_photo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtItemName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_photo"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtItemQuantity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtItemName"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_photo"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtItemPrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtItemQuantity"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_photo"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

CODE:

```
    public class InventoryItemRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InventoryItemRecyclerAdapter.InventoryItemViewHolder>  {


        onItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = null;

        /**
         *
         */
        public ArrayList<Product> mInventoryItemList;

        Context mContext;

        static String TAG = "InventoryItemRecyclerAdapter";

        Random random = new Random();

        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Constructor

        /**
         *
         * @param pInventoryItemList
         */
        public InventoryItemRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Product> pInventoryItemList) {
            mInventoryItemList = pInventoryItemList;
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

  @Override
    public InventoryItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        mContext = parent.getContext();

        // Inflate the Layout for an item
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_inventory_recycler_adapter, parent, false);

        // Instantiate ViewHolder
        InventoryItemViewHolder inventoryItemViewHolder = new InventoryItemViewHolder(v);

        return inventoryItemViewHolder;
    }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(InventoryItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

           ...
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        /**
         * Returns the total number of items in the data set hold by the adapter.
         *
         * @return The total number of items in this adapter.
         */
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mInventoryItemList.size();
        }

        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // View Holder

        /**
         * RecyclerView
         */
        public class InventoryItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Vars

            public CardView cardView;

            public RelativeLayout uiContainer;

            public TextView productName;
            public TextView productPrice;
            public TextView productQuantity;

            public ImageView productImage;

            public Product mProduct;

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Constructor

            public InventoryItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                cardView        = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
                productName     = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemName);
                productImage    = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_photo);
                productPrice    = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemPrice);
                productQuantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItemQuantity);
                uiContainer     = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlContainer);

                uiContainer.setOnClickListener(this);


            }

            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            /**
             * Called when a view has been clicked.
             *
             * @param v The view that was clicked.
             */
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.e("InventoryItemRecyclerAdapter", "onItemClick");

                // Throw a null pointer exception if this is null
                if (mOnItemClickListener == null) {
                    throw new NullPointerException("mOnItemClickListener is null in InventoryItemRecyclerAdapter");
                }

                // Delegate to its caller. Let it handle the work
                mOnItemClickListener.onRecyclerViewItemClick(this);

            }

            // -------------------------------------------------------------

        }


        // -----------------------------------------------------------------
        /**
         *  Interface for RecyclerView
         */
        public interface onItemClickListener {

            /**
             *
             * @param pItemViewHolder
             */
            public void onRecyclerViewItemClick(InventoryItemRecyclerAdapter.InventoryItemViewHolder pItemViewHolder);

        }

    }
```

I couldn't seem to find the problem thats causing this issue. Can I get any help on this please. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, try this: itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Thanks. I already have tried this. But this doesn't work. In this case item view is a card view. Rest of the components have been drawn over a relative layout

Comment: Hmm, I'm not really sure how to solve it :-/ Perhaps the onClickListener is not the listener your looking for... Have a try with on->ITEM<-ClickListener() 
Other solution could be: writing the listener straight behind the view xy.setOnItemClickListener(new OnClickListener... / onItemClickListener...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So I found the issue. The following two tags were the culprits here

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

When we set focusable and focusableInTouchMode = true basically it means that you are enabling a view to first focus on a touch and then be able to click.

Comment: Hey Ahemd I'm having the exact same issue. So did set `android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to ="false" ? - thanks

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, unfortunately its not working for me. Its probably something wrong with my implementation of Recycler View.

Im trying to set 2 strings to varying values depending on the position of the button clicked, `Log.d(TAG, "Position Clicked" + getLayoutPosition()+ textBoton1 + textBoton2);` on the first click strings(textBoton1,textBoton2,) return `null` on second click, strings are retrieved and performs action as expected.

Comment: Did you tried removing both. I mean focusable and focusableintouchmode? Same thing happened to me as well. Try removing both of them. If it didn't work, please share that particular layout and the related code so that I can make a test out of it and see what's different

Comment: Yes, I tried removing both, also tried setting programmatically `myv.setFocusable(false);` and `myv.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);` and no luck. Im sure Im doing something wrong, like setting the strings twice, Im new to recycleView. I'll try a few more things and if I can't figure it out I'll post a question so I can post my code and shoot you the link

Comment: Just keeping the focusableInTouchMode=false works. focusable by default is false.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, but the solution of setting focusable to false did not work in my case.

Instead, my problem was what I had set the onItemTouch listener in the activity that was holding my recycler view.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(...);
```

By removing this from my activity, my other touch listeners started to respond on single taps and not only double.