# RecyclerView item onClickListener doesn't work on a first click, but works on a second one

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

Adapter

```
public class MoviesAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MoviesViewHolder> {
private static final String baseMovieUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";
private ArrayList<Movie> movies;
private Context context;

public MoviesAdapter(ArrayList<Movie> movies, Context context) {
    this.movies = movies;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MoviesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    return new MoviesViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_square, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(position);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movies.size();
}


public class MoviesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private ConstraintLayout movieConstraint;
    private TextView movieName;
    private TextView movieRate;
    private ImageView moviePoster;

    public MoviesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        movieConstraint = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_holder_constraints);
        movieName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_name_tv);
        movieRate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_rating_tv);
        moviePoster = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_iv);
        movieConstraint.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void setData(int position) {
        movieConstraint.setTag(position);
        movieName.setText(movies.get(position).getMovieName());
        movieRate.setText(movies.get(position).getMovieRating() + "");
        if (!Objects.equals(movies.get(position).getMovieUrl(), "") && movies.get(position).getMovieUrl() != null) {
            Glide.with(moviePoster).load
                    (baseMovieUrl + movies.get(position).getMovieUrl())
                    .into(moviePoster);
        } else Log.i("No url!", "No url!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int pos = (int) view.getTag();
        view.setEnabled(false);
        changeActivity(pos);
        view.setEnabled(true);    // TODO Find a way to prevent 2 acctivites to open simultaniously
    }


    private void changeActivity(int pos) {
        Movie movie = movies.get(pos);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieInfo.class);
        intent.putExtra("movie", movie);
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, moviePoster, "profile");
        context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }
}
}
```

and the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/movie_holder_constraints"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="3dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/movie_cv"
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/inside_movie_constraints"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/movie_iv"
            android:layout_width="185dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_rating_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="9.5"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movie_name_tv"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/movie_name_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Guardian's Of The Galaxy"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/movie_iv" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

When clicking on the item in the recyclerView it wont open the activity or call the OnClickListener, after clicking another time the function is being called.
scrolling would also allow me to click on the items aswell.

I have heared changing the foucsable to false might solve this problem but as you can see in the xml it didn't.

***Edit for adapter:***
I changed the onClick to the onBindViewHolder, It fixed the problem although it doesn't feel to me like the right way to do it.
what do you say?

```
package com.example.galzaid.movies;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MoviesAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MoviesViewHolder> implements 
View.OnClickListener {
private static final String baseMovieUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500";
private ArrayList<Movie> movies;
private Context context;

public MoviesAdapter(ArrayList<Movie> movies, Context context) {
    this.movies = movies;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MoviesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    return new MoviesViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_square, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MoviesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(position);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    holder.getAdapterPosition();
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movies.size();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ImageView moviePoster = view.findViewById(R.id.movie_iv);
    changeActivity((int) view.getTag(), moviePoster);
}

private void changeActivity(int pos, ImageView moviePoster) {
    Movie movie = movies.get(pos);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieInfo.class);
    intent.putExtra("movie", movie);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
            makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, moviePoster, "profile");
    context.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}


public class MoviesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private ConstraintLayout movieConstraint;
    private TextView movieName;
    private TextView movieRate;
    private ImageView moviePoster;

    public MoviesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        movieConstraint = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_holder_constraints);
        movieName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_name_tv);
        movieRate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_rating_tv);
        moviePoster = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_iv);

    }

    public void setData(int position) {
        movieConstraint.setTag(position);
        movieName.setText(movies.get(position).getMovieName());
        movieRate.setText(movies.get(position).getMovieRating() + "");
        if (!Objects.equals(movies.get(position).getMovieUrl(), "") && movies.get(position).getMovieUrl() != null) {
            Glide.with(moviePoster).load
                    (baseMovieUrl + movies.get(position).getMovieUrl())
                    .into(moviePoster);
        } else Log.i("No url!", "No url!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [Double Click OnClickListener of a Recycler View Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991966/double-click-onclicklistener-of-a-recycler-view-adapter?rq=1), have you checked it?

Comment: I'd be willing to bed that it might be an issue with a different view absorbing the click event before it can get to the highest parent, maybe try setting the click listener on the cardview instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is in this line

```
movieConstraint.setOnClickListener(this);
```

You shouldn't set it to `ConstraintLayout`, change the above line to this

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And there is nothing wrong in setting your `onClickListener` in a `ViewHolder` constructor.

**EDIT:**

In order to get the position in `onClick` you can use `getAdapterPosition()` method.

Comment: Tried it, didn't fix it but it sounds like the programtically way to do it

Comment: @Gal try removing `setEnabled(false)`

Comment: it isn't it, I found something that fixed it but not sure that is the right way to do ill post it

Comment: I can call getAdapterPosition only from the holder, not from the onClick method.

Comment: @Gal check the edited answer, put the `itemView.setOnClickListener` back to the constructor, and make your `ViewHolder` implement the `onClickListener` as in the edit. That way you will be able to call `getAdapterPosition` from `onClickListener`. And also put the `onClick` back to where it was.

Comment: @Gal It does implement it, I didn't see it :)

Comment: @Gal the edit that you posted looks ok, it's a bit of a stretch though, but as you said it works. But implementing the `onClickListener` and setting it in a constructor should work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the OnClickListener in binding method, which in your case is `public void setData(int position)`

RecyclerView as its name says is reusing the views it created, so for every item you should set all the info from the start, including onClick listeners

That should fix your problems, and you will be able to resign from using setTag to differentiate the views

Avoid setting onClick listeners in ViewHolder constructors.

Comment: I don't think it's true, there is nothing wrong in setting `onClickListener` in a `ViewHolder`, it's much cleaner. Why do you say it should be avoided.

Comment: Well I find it to be the best approach, because when your item is more complicated, and you need to show/hide something or define if something is clickable based on your item model, you got to do it on every bind because if you don't, some items views will stay the way they've been bound when you scroll, and that's because of reusing already created views by RecyclerView

Comment: It's not the best approach, in fact, it's a bad approach. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33845951/7915814) answer to find out why. In short, if you put it in `onBindViewHolder` the `setOnClickListener` will be set for each and every item when it's actually unnecessary. If you don't want to set it in the `ViewHolder` (for some reason) it's better to do it in the `onCreateViewHolder` rather than `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Haven't you read what I said? I said it's good approach for me exactly because of that. Because of setting on each and every item. So when my item needs to be clickable, because it's model says so, I add the listener, and if not, I null the listener which was there previously if the item was recycled. I don't see any reason why setting listener in onBind differs in any way from setting text or different graphics etc.
This also corresponds with the fact that when you give the item selectableItemBackground you need to null the listener, otherwise the click animation will happen when it shouldnt

Comment: Yes, but you said avoid setting `onClick` in ViewHolder constructors, which is a bad advice. And the post that I linked actually explains why it's a bad approach, have you read it? There is no need to null the listeners they get recycled as well. And if you have an `onClickListener` in the constructor of the `ViewHolder` you can just use the `getAdapterPosition` to control which views can be clicked.